# Comparing consecutive rows and select rows where are subsequent is a specific value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows

```
structure(list(HospNum_Id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), VisitDate = c("13/02/03", "13/04/05", "13/05/12", 
"13/12/06", "13/04/12", "13/05/13", "13/06/14", "13/04/15", "03/04/15", 
"04/05/16", "04/06/16"), EVENT = c("EMR", "RFA", "nothing", "nothing", 
"EMR", "nothing", "EMR", "EMR", "RFA", "EMR", "nothing")), .Names = c("HospNum_Id", 
"VisitDate", "EVENT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

I want to only select the row  where the current row `EVENT` is "`EMR"` and the one prior to this (arranged by ascending date order) is "nothing" for each `HospNum_Id`.

My desired output is:

```
 HospNum_Id VisitDate EVENT
    2   13/12/06    nothing
    2   13/04/12    EMR
    2   13/05/13    nothing
    2   13/06/14    EMR
```

but my current output is:

```
  HospNum_Id VisitDate EVENT
       (int)     (chr) (chr)
1          2  13/04/12   EMR
2          2  13/06/14   EMR
3          2  13/04/15   EMR
```

Currently I have the following code but its letting me down I think because I am using first in the filter rather than a phrase meaning `"before the row that has EMR in the EVENT":`

```
Upstaging<-Therap %>% 
  arrange(HospNum_Id, as.Date(Therap$VisitDate, '%d/%m/%y')) %>% 
  group_by(HospNum_Id) %>% 
  filter(first(EVENT == "nothing") & EVENT == "EMR")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'HospNum_Id', we get the index ('i1') where 'EVENT' is "EMR" and the previous value is "nothing".  Use that index to get the previous element index ('i1-1') `sort` and get the row index (`.I`).  With that, we subset the rows.

```
library(data.table)
v1 <- setDT(df1)[,  {i1 <- which(EVENT == "EMR" & shift(EVENT)=="nothing")
              .I[sort(c(i1, i1-1))] } , by = HospNum_Id]$V1
df1[v1]
#   HospNum_Id VisitDate   EVENT
#1:          2  13/12/06 nothing
#2:          2  13/04/12     EMR
#3:          2  13/05/13 nothing
#4:          2  13/06/14     EMR
```

---

Or with similar methodology from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(HospNum_Id) %>% 
    mutate(ind = EVENT=="nothing" & lead(EVENT)=="EMR") %>% 
    slice(sort(c(which(ind),which(ind)+1))) %>% 
    select(-ind)
#   HospNum_Id VisitDate   EVENT   
#      <int>     <chr>   <chr>
#1          2  13/12/06 nothing
#2          2  13/04/12     EMR
#3          2  13/05/13 nothing
#4          2  13/06/14     EMR
```

Comment: OK. I would rather use dplyr as Im getting into it a bit more. The last line in the dplyr example throws the error Error: corrupt 'grouped_df', contains 4 rows, and 11 rows in groups but without  %>% select(-ind) I seem to get what I want. What doe the last line add?

Comment: @SebastianZeki  Did you meant the `slice` line or `select`?  I am not getting any error though.  The `select` line is to remove the 'ind' column.

Comment: OK. I meant the select column. But I think Ill just leave it out. As a last addendum if I want to just get results for when "nothing" occurs anywhere before EMR (not just in the row before) for a HospNum_Id. How would I ammend? If I need to ask as a separate question no problem

Comment: @SebastianZeki  It would be either due to some version difference or the structure of your dataset.  I guess it would be better to ask as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

just using elementary operation the desired result can be obtained.

Step 1. Load the data(

Step 2. Arrange the data frame by ascending date order

Step 3. Select the rows having event="EMR" and create a data frame and create a       data frame containing the previous rows.

Step 4. Remove duplicate and sort according to date

```
a<-loaded dataframe
a[order(as.Date(a$VisitDate,format="%d/%m/%Y")),,drop=FALSE]
revdf <- a[rev(rownames(a)),]
b<- revdf[which(revdf$EVENT=="EMR" ),] 
c<- revdf[which(revdf$EVENT=="EMR" )-1,]
d<-rbind(b,c)
e<-d[!duplicated(d),] 
f<-e[order(as.Date(e$VisitDate,format="%d/%m/%Y")),,drop=FALSE]
revdf1<-f[rev(rownames(f)),]
```

output:

```
  >revdf1
        HospNum_Id  VisitDate  EVENT
   11          3  04/06/16 nothing
   10          3  04/05/16     EMR
   8           2  13/04/15     EMR
   9           3  03/04/15     RFA
   7           2  13/06/14     EMR
   3           1  13/05/12 nothing
   5           2  13/04/12     EMR
   2           1  13/04/05     RFA
   1           1  13/02/03     EMR
```