# Select all rows where value present in subgroup

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows

```
    structure(list(HospNum_Id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), VisitDate = c("13/02/03", 
"13/04/05", "13/05/12", "13/12/06", "13/04/12", "13/05/13", "13/06/14", 
"13/04/15", "03/04/15", "04/05/16", "04/06/16", "13/05/03", "13/06/04", 
"13/04/05", "03/04/15", "04/05/16", "04/06/16"), EVENT = c("EMR", 
"RFA", "EMR", "nothing", "EMR", "nothing", "EMR", "EMR", "RFA", 
"EMR", "nothing", "RFA", "EMR", "EMR", "RFA", "EMR", "nothing"
)), .Names = c("HospNum_Id", "VisitDate", "EVENT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

I want to only select the HospNum_Ids where `RFA` occurs before `EMR` in the `EVENT` column. `RFA` can occur in any row before `EMR` not just the row before

```
   HospNum_Id   VisitDate   EVENT
1   13/02/03    EMR
1   13/04/05    RFA
1   13/05/12    EMR
3   03/04/15    RFA
3   04/05/16    EMR
3   04/06/16    nothing
4   13/05/03    RFA
4   13/06/04    EMR
4   13/04/05    EMR
4   03/04/15    RFA
4   04/05/16    EMR
4   04/06/16    nothing
```

@akrun very kindly provided me with something for consecutive runs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035323/comparing-consecutive-rows-and-select-rows-where-are-subsequent-is-a-specific-va/38035366?noredirect=1#comment63510968_38035366) but this is different

Comment: No. RFA can occur several times as can nothing or EMR. i have edited the example

Comment: Whenever EMR occurs if RFA has happened at any point for that HospNum_Id then I want all the rows for that HospNum_Id

Comment: I think its correct now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'HospNum_Id', we `order` the 'VisitDate' (after converting to `Date` class).  Based on `if` there are `any` "RFA" element in the "EVENT", we get the index of the first "RFA" element ('i1').  Using that we can get the row index for the whole rows of each 'Hosp_Num_id' that meets the condition  and then subset the dataset.

```
library(data.table)
v1 <- setDT(df1)[order(as.Date(VisitDate, "%d/%m/%y")), if(any(EVENT == "RFA"))  {
        i1 <- which(EVENT == "RFA")[1]
        .I[any(EVENT[(i1+1):.N] =="EMR")]}, by = HospNum_Id]$V1
df1[v1]
#    HospNum_Id VisitDate   EVENT
# 1:          1  13/02/03     EMR
# 2:          1  13/04/05     RFA
# 3:          1  13/05/12     EMR
# 4:          3  03/04/15     RFA
# 5:          3  04/05/16     EMR
# 6:          3  04/06/16 nothing
# 7:          4  13/05/03     RFA
# 8:          4  13/06/04     EMR
# 9:          4  13/04/05     EMR
#10:          4  03/04/15     RFA
#11:          4  04/05/16     EMR
#12:          4  04/06/16 nothing
```

---

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   arrange(HospNum_Id, as.Date(VisitDate, "%d/%m/%y")) %>% 
   group_by(HospNum_Id) %>%
   filter(any(EVENT =="RFA")) %>% 
   mutate(i1 = EVENT=="RFA" ) %>% 
   filter( any(EVENT[which(i1)[1]:n()]=="EMR")) %>%
   select(-i1)
#  HospNum_Id VisitDate   EVENT
#        <int>     <chr>   <chr>
#1           1  13/02/03     EMR
#2           1  13/04/05     RFA
#3           1  13/05/12     EMR
#4           3  03/04/15     RFA
#5           3  04/05/16     EMR
#6           3  04/06/16 nothing
#7           4  13/05/03     RFA
#8           4  13/06/04     EMR
#9           4  13/04/05     EMR
#10          4  03/04/15     RFA
#11          4  04/05/16     EMR
#12          4  04/06/16 nothing
```

Or a more compact approach would be

```
df1 %>%
     arrange(HospNum_Id, as.Date(VisitDate, "%d/%m/%y")) %>% 
     group_by(HospNum_Id) %>%
     filter(any(which(EVENT=="EMR") > which(EVENT == "RFA")[1]))
```

Comment: OK. Corrected the example. My actual data isn't date sorted. One reason I like dplyr is because this is easy to do. How do I add this to you r data.table example?

Comment: @SebastianZeki  Added the date sorting part.

Comment: @SebastianZeki  Updated with the `dplyr`.  It could be further improved with a single `filter`.  I am leaving that to you.

Comment: Great. Thanks @akrun